# Image doesn't get displayed in bootstrap thumbnail

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails

On my website I'm trying to make an overview of the customers with their logos, their name and a short description about them.

I'm using bootstrap thumbnails and chrome.

This is my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="/img/logos/first.jpg" alt="first">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>First</h3>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="/img/logos/second.png" alt="second">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Second</h3>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="/img/logos/third.png" alt="third">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Third</h3>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that I can't see any images. All I get is the alternative text. The path for the images is correct.

Can anybody please explain to me why I the images don't get displayed?

**Edit:**

This is my project structure:

[image: folders]

**SOLUTION**

I have found the error(s)!

- The correct path was "img/logos/first.jpg".
- I also modified the folder logos and all the images with "sudo chmod 755 FILENAME" (Linux).

Comment: Any 404 errors in the console? (Are the paths *really* correct?)

Comment: Obviously your markup is fine. http://jsfiddle.net/t5y3onx4/

Comment: can you screenshot the your folder structure. it could be a problem with incorrect folder where images are located. try to verify the images and folder if correct.

Comment: it should actually work with `img/Kundenlogos/first.jpg` You might check if the file type is correct (you have .png in your structure)  and if the spelling is correct. If this doesn't work check if your browser is caching the image.

Answer (score 1):

The path `/img/Kundenlogos/third.png` is relative to your root directory. You probably have something like `/Webseite/img/Kundenlogos/third.png` for example. Include that as well.

If your structure looks like this:

```
folder
    html
        file.html
        index.html
    img
        Kundenbilder
            first.jpg
            second.jpg
```

you can also use `../img/Kundenlogos/third.png`